# Array dimension terminology

Tags: c#, arrays, terminology

When talking about an n-dimensional array in C#, are the dimensions left to right, or right to left? That is:

```
new int[0,1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
new int[4,3,2,1,0]
```

For clarification, I'm talking about how you would describe each index, not how to access arrays.

Comment: Describe it however you want.  Those are the dimension and you access them in that order.   I am not getting the purpose of 0 dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from left to right, as expected. This maps directly to indexing an array.

Comment: Just making sure, the leftmost length would be the length of the zeroth dimension, right?

Comment: Yes. This can be confirmed with [Array.GetLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It uses dimension as a parameter.